# Elements are not get in IE Browser

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

Elements are not get in IE Browser. i am using IE 11 Browser. While I am run my code then Error is displaying in my consol as `Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit) 2.47.0.0`

```
Listening on port 20577

Error show := org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == Id_user_name_id (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.17 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
System info: host: 'VDJSDEV2-PC', ip: '172.16.1.220', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:20577/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 8bd16d35-c13d-46f7-b6cf-f9a7ddd54dda
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=Id_user_name_id}
```

And I am using these Jar files

```
selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar
selenium-ie-driver-2.47.0.jar
selenium-java-2.47.1-srcs.jar
selenium-java-2.47.1.jar
IEDriverServer_Win32_2.47.0
```

Comment: Welcome - always post your code! Please see [ask] and the [FAQ]s - good luck!

Comment: can you please share your HTML Code so it can help us to help me

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem, and my solution is:
Modified IE setting to display both secure and non secure contents.

1. Set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value, the value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone (I checked "Enable Protected Mode" all).
2. Way to set protected mode: choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu ->  click on the Security tab. For each zone (Internet/Local Internet/Trusted Web Sites/Restricted Sites), check the check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode".
3. Restart your IE browser.

It works on me, hope it can help you too.

Answer (score -3):

Some suggestion which may help.

- Check the element id is unique in the page and actually exist; can you post the html page ( just the element and its parent parent if possible)
- Increase the browser capabilities  timeout  to double the existing one
  before you search for the element by id

  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
- Try with different Driver (Firefox or Chrome) and see if the problem persist
- Try to search the element by selector; if you post the html page, I can help in sending some suggestion

Cheers
Alan Mehio
London